# convergence of functions on probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, game-theory, weak-convergence

I am studying a problem in game theory, but I am lacking on knowledge to deal with a continuum of distribution functions convergence.

$\mathfrak{F}([0,1])$ is the set of distribution functions over the set $[0,1]$.

$f$ and $f^n$ are functions that to each $x\in [0,1]$ chose a distribution function on $\mathfrak{F}([0,1])$  $f, f^n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathfrak{F}([0,1])$. Is there a good metric to evaluate the distance of $f$ and $f^n$? what kind of convergence is better suited for this, what is $f^n \rightarrow f$? Pointwise convergence, $f^n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ and supremum metric?

If $h:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous and   $ g \in \mathfrak{F}([0,1])$, is $E_h=\int_{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2} h(x,y) \partial (g \times f)$ well defined? When can I say that $E^n_h=\int_{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2} h(x,y) \partial (g^n \times f^n)$  converges to  $E_h$. If $f^n$  was just a distribution from $\mathfrak{F}([0,1])$, there was no problem, but with $f^n$ defined as it is can I apply a weak convergence argument here?

Comment: To get a feel for how to handle general convergence of probability measures, read the first(ish) chapters of [Billingsley](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0471197459/ref=redir_mdp_mobile), still the standard reference. $E_h$ is well-defined as it integrates, on a compact set, a continuous (and so bounded) function. As to convergence to it, I don't remember, but this is is discussed in Billingsley.

Comment: $E_h$ needs to be redifined, it is $E_h=\int_{x \in [0,1]} \int_{y \in [0,1]} h(x,y) \partial f(x) \partial g$ the distribution on $y$ depends on the value of $x$, if $h(x)= \int_{y \in [0,1]} h(x,y) \partial f(x)$, I can rewrite as $E_h=\int_{x \in [0,1]} h(x) \partial g$, and something must be demanded for this to be well defined, right?

I will recheck Billingsley, thx.

Comment: I think you have a typo, and meant to type $\tilde{h}(x)= \int_{y \in [0,1]} h(x,y) \partial f(y)$, and yes, I see this is different from the case where the measure you integrate over isn't also a function of $x$ ($y$). But I think other than the usual conditions needed to apply Fubini, this integral will be always defined for continuous $h$ on compact sets. I wish I had a more direct reference to game theory, but this is in my distant past, and I can't give you a more satisfying answer. :(

Comment: Answers to game theory appear to be a bit sparse on this site, but maybe linking the paper might help. The setup is unusual (even more abstract) compared to what are common weak convergence questions.

Comment: Maybe it is not well defined but there is no typo. $f:[0,1] \rightarrow  \mathfrak{F}([0,1])$. So there is a probability measure for each $x$, when i wrote $\partial f(x)$ in $\int_{y \in [0,1]} h(x,y) \partial f(x)$ i really meant it, i was refering to the measure associated with that $x$. Naturally Fubini is not applicable here, I think. I would love to link to the paper if I had it, I am working on it, but believe me the setting is much harder to understand.

Comment: Maybe I misread it; I thought you had $f(y)$, and $g(x)$, that's all - the parametrization which makes this so much harder than simpler cases was clear. Gl then! My time with game theory is over 10 years ago (it was what all the big names at my school did, but after course work, I didn't get much into it myself anyway). In any case, if you get that deeply into convergence in measure (as this should surely be handled), Billingsley is time well-spent.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function $f$ from $[0,1]$ into the space $\mathcal{B}$ of (say, Borel) probability measures on $[0,1]$. If you give $\mathcal{B}$ the topology of convergence in probability, it's a metric space. If $f$ is continuous in this topology (and the usual one on $[0,1]$), it is natural to consider the sup distance.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the game theoretic context in which you are considering this.